# Как оформить в javadoc передачу изменяемого обьекта

Tags: java, javadoc

В метод передаются объекты с данными, и объекты в которые записывается ответ.
Пока записал как

```
 * @param nu      = # of user
 * @param nr      = # of ref
```

...

```
* @param @return iu       = # user indices 
* @param @return ir       = # ref indices
```

но может есть более эстетичный вариант?

Comment: В java  не поддерживаются переменные out

Comment: Ну, формально можно передать обьект в метод и модифицыровать его там. Да, это не совсем правильно, но это легаси. с которым пришлось столкнуться(

Comment: Тогда будет не стыковка по типам, так что не надо придумывать велосипед, а использовать стандартные определения методов.